# Same App loaded for sharing multiple files

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio-2.2, android-sharing

I'm sharing two kinds of files from my code, zip files and 3gp files, i'm using the same code for both and the same FileProvider wich i defined in Manifest and xml sharepaths file.

The share action presents choices for zip file each time, but audio files, from the first time i tested sharing them to google drive, no choices pops up , the google drive app executes each time i want to share audio files, it's annoying since user have to get choice all time.

```
private Intent setShareIntent(ArrayList<Uri> uris){
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    shareIntent.setType("audio/3gpp");
    shareIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    return shareIntent;
}
private ArrayList<Uri> getChekcedRecordsUris(){
    SparseBooleanArray sba = pRecordsList.getCheckedItemPositions();
    int position;
    ArrayList<Uri> archivesUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    for(int i = 0; i< sba.size();i++){
        if(sba.valueAt(i)){
            position = sba.keyAt(i);
            File selectedArchive = pRecordsFilesAdapter.getItem(position);
            archivesUris.add(FileProvider.getUriForFile(getBaseContext(), "ma.altaiir.app.appfileProvider", selectedArchive));
        }
    }
    return archivesUris;
}
private void shareCheckedItems(){
    Intent shareIntent = setShareIntent(getChekcedRecordsUris());
    if(shareIntent.resolveActivity(FilesActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null){
        FilesActivity.this.startActivity(shareIntent);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), MyApplication.getMyAppContext().getResources().getString(R.string.toast_no_intent_app_chooser),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the mistake, it comes from the mime type i used for 3gp files, witch are basically video containers , so i had to use either audio/* or video/3gp.

audio/* solved my problem and now the intent is presenting a chooser for user.